# construct tuples from selection with repetition

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

Given an input array with lists of tuples with a count, e.g.,

```
r, s = 0.5, 2.0   # floats, given, guaranteed nonzero, guaranteed nonequal

[
    ((+r, -r), 2),
    ((+s, -s), 1),
    ((0,), 2),
    # ...
]
```

I would like to construct a list of all combinations which has two of `(+r, -r)` (could both be `+r`), one of `(+s, -s)`, and two `0`, i.e.

```
(+r, 0, -s, +r, 0),
(0, 0, -r, +r, +s),
...
```

There could be any number of tuples. The order doesn't matter.

Is there way to achieve this with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)?

Comment: Are `+r` and `-r` supposed to be strings?

Comment: In the `s` case, how do you determine which of the two `s`s to choose?  Or does it not matter?  Additionally, what if the count given in `x[1]` is greater than `len(x[0])`?

Comment: @alani floats, clarified

Comment: @0x5453 I want all combinations, so those with `+s` as well as those with `-s`.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Slowly realising that to get this right avoiding any double-counting is going to be a substantially harder problem than I first imagined. Specifically, simply expanding to `[(+r, -r), (+r, -r), (+s, -s), (0,), (0,)]` then using `product` and the permutations for each one would lead to double-counting of combinations that contain both `+r` and `-r`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not going to have time to look at this myself, but I would suggest to anyone doing so that you verify that your permutations are all in fact unique (maybe use `collections.Counter` and check for any values >1).

Comment: How is the "input array with lists of tuples with a count" connected to the "list of all combinations" you want to get?

Comment: @zabop The example in the post is not clear?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I believe hes asking:  you say "given an input array", and also "construct a list of all combinations".  Are you ignoring the input list and just creating your own list of combinations, or are you trying to find combinations that already exist in your input list (filtering a list?)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, product, chain, permutations

r, s = 0.5, 2.0
l = ((+r, -r), 2), ((+s, -s), 1), ((0,), 2)

seen = set()
for p in product(*[list(combinations_with_replacement(v, cnt)) for v, cnt in l]):
    for c in permutations(chain.from_iterable(p), sum(cnt for _, cnt in l)):
        if c not in seen:
            print(c)
            seen.add(c)
```

Prints:

```
(0.5, 0.5, 2.0, 0, 0)
(0.5, 0.5, 0, 2.0, 0)
(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 2.0)
(0.5, 2.0, 0.5, 0, 0)
(0.5, 2.0, 0, 0.5, 0)
(0.5, 2.0, 0, 0, 0.5)
(0.5, 0, 0.5, 2.0, 0)
(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 2.0)
(0.5, 0, 2.0, 0.5, 0)
(0.5, 0, 2.0, 0, 0.5)
(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 2.0)
(0.5, 0, 0, 2.0, 0.5)

...

(0, -2.0, -0.5, 0, -0.5)
(0, -2.0, 0, -0.5, -0.5)
(0, 0, -0.5, -0.5, -2.0)
(0, 0, -0.5, -2.0, -0.5)
(0, 0, -2.0, -0.5, -0.5)
```